# Text formatting in the description field of a JIRA, like in its comment areas

Tags: formatting, format, jira

On JIRA tickets I can format comments entries at will : there's a toolbar with many choices for that, color, styles, underline...

[image]

But how do I get the same for description field ("descriptif" in French)?
Because what people read for explanation of a story/task/ticket, is mainly this content.

And currently the only thing we can do is to write on some descriptions "*Look at comments to learn the purpose of this item/understand something*" because a plain text is sometimes not enough to explain things.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled with renderers under Field Configuration Scheme.

- Open Project settings -> Field Configuration.
- Find the field "Descriptif"
- There should be a text called "Renderers", click that. (In some version, it may be inside Edit)
- Select "Wiki-style Renderer"
- Click "Update" button.

And voila, it should be formatted like the Comment field.

Also, for further info you can check [following Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-change-text-custom-field-to-rich-text-editor-1026536446.html).